# nokia 3110c with fedora

Tags: nokia, fedora

hai friends

In my application i want to send sms using nokia 3310c mobile which is connected to a fedora core 8.while connecting the a new file named ttyACM0 is created in /dev directory
i tried to send at commands using this file

the first at command is returning ok ie., at
then i tried at+cmgf=1 return ok
then tried at+cmgl="ALL"

it returns error...........

it displayes ring while a incoming call comes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Symbian phones don't support this command. Take a look at [this post](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showpost.php?p=575863&postcount=25) on the Nokia developer discussion board.

Answer (score 2):

AT+CMGL is for Reading sms
but that command is not working 
for nokia phones. It works fine with
Non-Nokia phones.

To get the java code for all this 
stuff visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-sms-api/

For sending messages(from nokia phones) u need to set
the mode of the phone to PDU (at+cmgf=0) which is the 
default state by the way.

For non-nokia phones set the mode to Text ( at+cmgf=1 ) then
send ur msg in text fromat and not in pdu.

The best way is try all your AT commands on minicom ( in linux )
and see the output immediately. Here u will can communicate with ur 
phone directly ( via the At commands though).